# get url twitter trends return always null

Tags: android, twitter

i am trying to get list of tweeter trends, than when i choose a trend it will send me to his url.

```
ArrayList<String> NAME = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> URLS = new ArrayList<String>();    

for (Trends trends : dailyTrends) {

        for (Trend trend : trends.getTrends()) {

            if (JOBS.size() < 25){

                URLS.add(trend.getUrl());

                NAME.add(trend.getName());

        }

}
```

Getting names work very fine, but i can not get urls, it always return null. Why? And how can i fixe it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which library you are using, but getting Twitter Trend URLs should be fairly easy.

The [documentation for Daily Trends](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/daily) shows that the URL is not returned.

You will get something like this in return:

```
{

"trends": {

"2011-01-14 15:20": [

  {

    "name": "#confessionhour",

    "events": null,

    "promoted_content": null,

    "query": "#confessionhour"

  },

  {

    "name": "#thankssuju",

    "events": null,

    "promoted_content": null,

    "query": "#thankssuju"

  },
...
```

The trick here is to use the "query" element.  You can then use this to create a URL.

If you want to point the user to the Twitter mobile search for that trend, you would use:

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/search/%23thankssuju
```

In your library I would expect you can get this using getQuery();